# Problem creating a new project with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning to create projects with laravel, I am using PHP 8. When creating a new project

`composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project`

I got the problem

```
Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: You should check server requirements. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#server-requirements

Comment: What is your php version? Do you use `apache`?

Comment: If your PHP version >= 5.3.0, fileinfo should be enabled by default.

Comment: I did it like this: 01 `composer create-project laravel/laravel app --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo`. 02: php artisan serve (terminal). 03: generate app key -> refresh now.

Answer (score 32):

You need to uncomment this line in the `php.ini` file located in your PHP installation folder:

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

Remove the semicolon and save the file.

```
extension=fileinfo
```

Comment: I was getting the same error and this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: In My case, I had to uncomment ";extension=intl"

Comment: It depends on the error, the above error says `require ext-fileinfo`.